# passwd command will not prompt for password to change too

Tags: linux, debian, passwd

I am trying to change password on multiple accounts including root.

It will not prompt for password to change too.

I saw someone suggested to remove and re-install passwd, this bricked one of my VMs and so that is not an option.

This is happening on about 25 new VM's installed in Azure so need to fix it.

I also could not find any other programs that will change password in linux.

*in root - trying to change user netadm*

It simply says, here your pass is updated without letting me specify the password.

```
root@host:/home/user# passwd netadm
passwd: password updated successfully
```

OS is Debian 11

I can get in because I installed tacacs & passwordless ssh login pub/priv keypair yet now I cannot get into the original local account.

Tried to delete the account - netadm and try again. Tried a new account netadm2, same thing.

```
root@host:/etc/pam.d# sudo useradd netadm2
root@host:/etc/pam.d# passwd netadm2
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: No idea, but did you try `alias passwd`? The other thing would be using `strace` or `ltrace` on the command to find out what's going on.

Comment: thank you, on the strace reminder - following this lead me to pam.d ---> first it reads passwd ----> then common-password and some items in there were changed with the tacacs installation. After fixing common-password - this is good. Thanks